# TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1c0164080]: 12:8 Err(-65554) and HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [12:8])

Tags: ios, swift, ssl-certificate, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to make a dataTask to a server that has ssl certificate, but I am getting this errors:

```
TIC TCP Conn Failed [2:0x1c0165340]: 12:8 Err(-65554)
HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [12:8])
```

I am using a url with https, I think that I need to do something else to allow https connections.

Here my code:

```
func doTask( completion: @escaping (_ dictionary: NSDictionary) -> Void)->Void{
    self.start()
    let URL = NSURL(string: Constants.baseUrl+self.url)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL as URL)
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self.data)
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
        let cleanJson = ServerResponseValidator().isJson(data: data);
        if(data != nil){
            let outputStr  = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
            print(outputStr!)
            completion(cleanJson)
            self.stop()
            if error != nil{
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                return
            }
        }else{
            completion(NSDictionary())
        }


    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>preguntapp.mx</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Did you get your solution?

Comment: Yes it was a server error